# Reset Jquery Datatable pagination after external row filter

Tags: jquery, pagination, datatables, datatables-1.10

I have some static data binded to data. Then I have applied pagination to the table using jquery datatable.net plugin.

Now I have external filtering logic, which hides and shows rows. I managed to filter the records on all pages. But some how I am not able to reset the pagination (i.e page numbers) as per the filtered records. Only the records from all the pages are gone, but pagination is not reset. e.g. Earlier I had 100 records and 10 pages(10 records per page), after filtering I have 30 records, so I should only see 3 pages, instead I see all 10 pages and some of the pages are blank.

I have following code:

```
function initSorting() {
var odatatable = $("#tblLoanPayment").DataTable({
    "sDom": '<p"top"><"bottom"><"clear">',
    paging: true,
    searching: false,
    ordering: true,
    select: false,
    lengthChange: false,
    pagingType: "full_numbers",
    "oLanguage": {
        "sInfo": "_START_ - _END_ of _TOTAL_",
        "oPaginate": {
            "sNext": ">",
            "sPrevious": "<",
            "sFirst": "<<",
            "sLast": ">>"
        }
    },
    "aaSorting": [],
    bInfo: false,
    "columnDefs": [{
        "targets": [2, 3, 4, 5],
        "orderable": false
    }]
});
return odatatable;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    checkNEnableButton();
    var odatatable = initSorting();
    $(".chosen-select").change(function () {
        $('#tblLoanPayment').DataTable().destroy();
        //some add remove row logic here...
        initSorting();
    });
});
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can probably just redraw the table:  odatatable.draw();

Comment: tried.. not working :(

Comment: My advice would be to keep things simple and not create & destroy the table onchange.  I would create the table on document.ready() and call draw() after changing the underlining data.

Comment: Table is filled with static data. On document.ready() I use datatable to initialise paging and sorting. But if I do not use destroy then filtering happens only on current page, not on all the pages. Hence I have destroyed and recreated the table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll make my comment as answer:  My advice would be to keep things simple and not create & destroy the table onchange. I would create the table on document.ready() and call draw() after changing the underlining data.  Here's how I did in my application:

```
sortFilteredGridData();
table.clear();
table.rows.add(filteredGridData);
table.draw();
```

Filtered grid data is an array of data.

Comment: In most of the scenarios it will work, but I have static table with data. My filtering is not based on table data, instead it hides and shows rows on diffrerent logic. Also I dont have json data to bind to. Hence it wont work for me.

Comment: You can still access the underlining data from the table from table.rows().  You can get the data, remove the rows, and redraw the table.

Comment: Does this mean I ll have to filter the table.rows() and I should not do rows hide and show explicitly?

Comment: From the Destroy() documentation (https://datatables.net/reference/api/destroy()):  This function can be useful if you require to destroy and create new tables based on new criteria with different initialisation settings or a different number of columns in the table, as they cannot be change on-the-fly through the API. If you do not require to make changes to the features of the table and simply alter the data contained in the table, then consider using the clear(), ajax.url() and rows.add() methods.

Comment: I stopped filtering records externally. And filtered records using .search(searchText, true, false).draw() function. Addressed issues regarding destroying and recreating.